# Table alignment problem

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JAm6g/4/)

For some reason, the left table takes up more space than it should, forcing the right table to the right part of the page. I want the text just to the right of the border encapsulating the AAA and BBB td's.

Should be an easy problem, but haven't be able to solve this problem despite my best efforts.

Comment: Would using percentage widths help?

Comment: Do you really need table within the table?

Comment: Yes, nested tables are nessesary (for requirements outside of this question). I'll try percentage widths but I'd prefer if the tables just used up the space nessesary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
<td width="100%">
```

for the 2nd column of your main table to force this one to the maximum available width.
See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JAm6g/7/).

But your example contains invalid HTML. You shouldn't use `<hr />` outside of a `<td>`. Also, if you do not display tabular data you should use markup without using `<table>`.

Comment: Ah, that worked splendidly. And thanks for the invalid HR remark.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt this a long text without any spaces problem. Normally content have space (regular word boundaries). Try putting in some space in your text (AAAAA) and then check.

Comment: Alternatively, use a Lorem Ipsum (www.lipsum.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the width=100% from the table tag the right column will go to the left.

[image: The result]

This is what is showing for me after i do this.

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong, could you provide a working JSFiddle?

Comment: if you remove the width=100% in the first line of code in this link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JAm6g/4/) and press run it should work (it does for me)

Comment: Ah, it worked for me aswell. Removed it from the wrong table before.